# How to update table records with another table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a problem with updating records in my table. I am doing research all day but it is just beyond me.

Basics: I have two tables

TABLE1
[image]

TABLE2
[image]

I need to update nr_g from TABLE1 with id from TABLE2 but only where 'kraj' 'region' 'nazwa_hotelu' from TABLE1 is equal 'country' 'region' 'hotelName' from TABLE2

my trying so far:

```
UPDATE merlinx u
        LEFT JOIN
    merlinx_new s ON u.nr_g != s.id
SET 
    u.nr_g = s.id
WHERE
    u.kraj = s.country AND u.nazwa_hotelu = s.hotelName AND u.region = s.region
```

That is updating me only 4 rows... and 1592 are unsafe statements

another shot of mine:

```
UPDATE merlinx_merged 
SET 
    nr_g = (SELECT 
            merlinx_new.id
        FROM
            merlinx_new
                INNER JOIN
            merlinx_merged
        WHERE
            merlinx_new.country = merlinx_merged.kraj
                AND merlinx_new.hotelName = merlinx_merged.nazwa_hotelu
                AND merlinx_new.region = merlinx_merged.region)
```

And that is just throwing errors.

My mind is fried after 8 hours wasted on it. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is in your join statement. You have

```
   LEFT JOIN merlinx_new s ON u.nr_g != s.id
```

You shouldn't have to have the ON criteria in that (if I'm understanding your question correctly).

This should do the trick if you want to overwrite merlinx.nr_g with the value from merlinx_new.id if all of your criteria matches in the WHERE clause.

```
UPDATE merlinx u, merlinx_new s
SET u.nr_g = s.id
WHERE u.kraj = s.country AND u.nazwa_hotelu = s.hotelName AND u.region = s.region
```